# how to get a Linq select value from dynamic?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I'm writing a method to let the client decide which fields they want to select from a table

here is what i do so far

```
public IList<User> List(int? roleId, int? sequence, string    name,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<User, dynamic>> selector)
{
var query = context.Users.AsQueryable();
if (roleId.HasValue && roleId.Value > 0)
   query = query.Where(x => x.RoleId == roleId);

if (sequence.HasValue && sequence.Value > 0)
   query = query.Where(x => x.Sequence == sequence);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
   query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name));

query = query.OrderBy(x => x.UserId);

var result = query.Select(selector).ToList();
var users = new List<User>();
User user = null;
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            user=new User();
            user.UserId = item.id;
            user.Name = item.name;
            //user.Email = item.email;
            //user.Sequence = item.sequence;
            users.Add(user);
        }

return users;
}
```

it compile an error says: item.id is not define, but i can see item{id=4,name="sam"....}

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know what's in your result? You could select to `string` in your selector...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give ability for client code to choose, what fields it wants to retrieve from database, then why do you restrict return type to `User`?

Let the client code choose, which return type it should use:

```
public IList<T> List(int? roleId, int? sequence, string    name,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<User, T>> selector)
{
   // ...
   query = query.OrderBy(x => x.UserId);

   return query.Select(selector).ToList();
}
```

Otherwise, I can't imagine, how are you going to convert anything, returned from selector, into `User` instances.

Comment: because there are other parts which are already using User as model,but yours are good advice, i think i'll try this way,thx.